# Installing a hadoop cluster for a class and my hadoop cluster nodes are not starting

Tags: hadoop

I am trying to spin up a hadoop cluster for a database class I am in and I just cannot seem to get the namenodes or data nodes to start.  I am following the tutorial here: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-spin-up-a-hadoop-cluster-with-digitalocean-droplets.  I have installed the master and each of the three worker nodes in virtual machines using VMware.  I have followed this tutorial to a T to include editing each of the config files in the tutorial.  I then ran the ./bin/hdfs namenode -format command followed by ./sbin/start-dfs.sh and ./sbin/start-yarn.sh scripts.  I recieved all of the appropriate output stating that these nodes are starting, however when i run the jps command i see no nodes started on the master and the only node that starts on the worker nodes is the nodemanager process.  Any ideas on what I am missing?

Comment: Need more clarification. Provide some logs please.

Comment: Hadoop isn't a database... Please follow official Apache site "to a T" before using external sources